# Uncaught TypeError: setInterval(...).unref is not a function

Tags: javascript, electron, discord.js

I was trying to use discord.js to get current client ID, I installed discord.js, @discordjs/rest discord-api-types and here's my code

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login("Your Token");

const commands = require("./commands.json");

const rest = new REST({ "version": "9" }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");
        if (process.argv.length) {
            await rest.put(
                Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID, process.argv[0]), { "body": commands }
            );
        } else {
            await rest.put(
                Routes.applicationCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID), { "body": commands }
            );
        }
        console.log("Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: setInterval(...).unref is not a function
> at new RESTManager ([PATH]\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RESTManager.js:23:51)
> at new BaseClient ([PATH]\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:27:17)
> at new Client ([PATH]\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:38:5)
> at file:///[PATH]/assets/app.js:2:16

Comment: where is the error occuring?

Comment: [PATH]\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RESTManager.js:23
Uncaught TypeError: setInterval(...).unref is not a function

Comment: Which *line* though?

Comment: What are your discord.js and node versions?

Comment: It's possible that the `setInterval()` function in Electron is the DOM one and not the native NodeJS one (which is the one used for Discord.js)